# python 2.7 getting below error while running the script

Tags: python

I have the following code in Python 2.7 and am receiving the following error.

```
import os,subprocess,re
f = open("/var/tmp/disks_out", "w")
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ["df", "-h"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
out, err = proc.communicate()
for line in out:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
f1 = open("/var/tmp/disks_out","r")
disks = []
for line in f1:
    m = re.search(r"(c\dt\d.{19})",line)
    if m:
        disk = m.group[1]
        disks.append(disk)
print(disks)
```

Error:

```
disk = m.group[1]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is unsubscriptable
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Indentation matters in Python. Badly indented Python code is not a [mcve]. If we guess how it is supposed to be indented, we might miss problems that we can't see. Please [edit] your question to accurately depict the indentation of your code.

Comment: ... but you probably meant `m.group(1)` instead of `m.group[1]` .

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is -

```
m.group[1]
```

But rather it should be -

```
m.group(1)
```

Look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group)

Example from docs -

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(\w+) (\w+)", "Isaac Newton, physicist")
>>> m.group(0)       # The entire match
'Isaac Newton'
>>> m.group(1)       # The first parenthesized subgroup.
'Isaac'
>>> m.group(2)       # The second parenthesized subgroup.
'Newton'
>>> m.group(1, 2)    # Multiple arguments give us a tuple.
('Isaac', 'Newton')
```

What you are doing instead is-

```
disk=m.group[1]
# Trying to slice a builtin method, in this case, you are trying to slice group()
# and hence
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is unsubscriptable
```

Square brackets `[]` are the subscript operator. If you try to apply the subscript operator to an object that does not support it, you get the error.

Comment: I am able to get  list show below.But i want to remove last two character from list                                                                                                           
  (574) # ./f4.py
['c0t5000CCA025A29894d0s0']